# The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have a problem trying to implement a filtering expression to filter a list of **entities** :

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

This is the code :

```
public IList<DocumentEntry> GetDocumentEntriesForRateAdjustmentTry2(
    string username, Rate rate, List<RatePeriod> ratePeriods)
{
    var dimensionLibManager = new DimensionLibManager();
    var currentVersionRateGroups = rate.CurrentRateVersion.RateGroups.ToList();

    Expression<Func<DocumentEntry, IList<RateGroup>, int, bool>> dimensionMatchesExpression =
        (documentEntry, rateGroups, dimensionInfoId) =>
        rateGroups.Any(
            rg =>
            rg.Dimension1.All(character => character == '*')
            ||
            documentEntry.DocumentEntryDimensions.Any(
                ded =>
                ded.DimensionInfo.Position == dimensionInfoId
                &&
                dimensionLibManager.GetDimensionSegments(rate.CompanyId, username, dimensionInfoId, ded.Value).Any(
                    seg => ded.Value.Substring(seg.SegmentStart, seg.SegmentLength) == seg.SegmentValue)));
    var dimensionMatches = dimensionMatchesExpression.Compile();

    var documentEntries = this.ObjectSet.Where(de => dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 1));

    var result = documentEntries.ToList(); // The error happens here.

    return result;
}
```

I suspect that **dimensionMatchesExpression** cannot be traduced into SQL because inside it calls another library's method (**dimensionLibManager.GetDimensionSegments**) to filter documents based on specific parameters.

Is there a way (other than using LinqKit or any additionnal extention library) that I can make this work ?

The reason why I want to use an Expression to act as a filter is because, ultimately, I would like to to this :

```
var documentEntries = this.ObjectSet.Where(de => 
    dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 1)
    && dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 2)
    && dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 3)
    && dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 4));
```

Also, how can I actually debug that kind of problem ? The error message is pretty vague. How can I track down the exact node that is causing the error ?

Comment: No way around this. Only works with LINQ to Objects.

Comment: The fundamental issue is the difference between lambda expression and lambda functions. The inside of the Where function parameter currently has a lambda function with a lambda expression wrapping it. You need a pure expression tree for this query. Combining expressions is really hard.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the issue.

```
var documentEntries = this.ObjectSet.Where(de => dimensionMatches(de, currentVersionRateGroups, 1));
```

I don't think that row number works with Linq2EF.

```
public IList<DocumentEntry> GetDocumentEntriesForRateAdjustmentTry2(
    string username, Rate rate, List<RatePeriod> ratePeriods)
{
    var dimensionLibManager = new DimensionLibManager();
    var currentVersionRateGroups = rate.CurrentRateVersion.RateGroups.ToList();

    Expression<Func<DocumentEntry, int, bool>> dimensionMatchesExpression =
        (documentEntry, rateGroups, dimensionInfoId) =>
        currentVersionRateGroups.Any(
            rg =>
            rg.Dimension1.All(character => character == '*')
            ||
            documentEntry.DocumentEntryDimensions.Any(
                ded =>
                ded.DimensionInfo.Position == dimensionInfoId
                &&
                dimensionLibManager.GetDimensionSegments(rate.CompanyId, username, dimensionInfoId, ded.Value).Any(
                    seg => ded.Value.Substring(seg.SegmentStart, seg.SegmentLength) == seg.SegmentValue)));


    var documentEntries = this.ObjectSet.Where(dimensionMatchesExpression);

    var result = documentEntries.ToList(); // The error happens here.

    return result;
}
```

Although I don't understand why you want to use an expression to do this. You could just inline it all...

Just realised a few days ago the solution to your problem...bit of a hack...

```
public Expression<Func<DocumentEntry, int, bool>> CreateWhereClause(stuff);

public IList<DocumentEntry> GetDocumentEntriesForRateAdjustmentTry2(
string username, Rate rate, List<RatePeriod> ratePeriods)

{
    using(var db = new Context())
    {
        IQueryable<DocumentEntry> foo = db.Foos;
        foreach(var i =0; i <4; i++)
        {
            foo = foo.Where(DocumentEntry(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I want to use an Expression.